# VPS server bundle install only runs as root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, root, vps, digital-ocean

I am building a digital ocean VPS server via ubuntu and I am having issues with my bundler.  I have had this issue before on the local machine but I have no idea how to fix this issue.  To be as specific as possible, I ran:

```
bundle install
```

in my application folder.  It gives me the "Don't run bundle as root" message and I am not sure how to NOT run it as root here.  On the local machine, I run:

```
sudo bundle install
```

to run as root and on the VPS server I am not using that sudo but it still runs as root=(
Does anyone know what I have to do to get bundler working on the VPS server?  Thanks a ton for any advice!

Comment: Well... are you logged on VPS as user? did you create user, home directory, etc., or are you working as root?

Comment: Thank you! I must need to create a user! defiantly working as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is pretty easy, you are working as `root` so you need to create some `user` first.